# Coverting a foreach loop containing an if statement into linq method syntax in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert this to a linq statement with method syntax. I am not sure how to do it when teh foreach loop has an if statement. In the code below, MyMethodToConvert replaces the string "Tomorrow" to DateTime.Now

```
foreach (var data in MyCollection)
        {
            if (data.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow"))
            {
                data.DeliveryDate = MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate);
            }
        }
```

I tried this, t didn't work

```
MyCollection = MyCollection.Select(a =>
                {
                    a.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow")
                        ? MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate)
                        : a.DeliveryDate)
                    ;
                    return a;
        }).ToList();
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: LINQ is great when it makes code succinct and clear. LINQ is not great when it obscures what is happening. Your `foreach` is clear as to purpose and result. Don't change it.

Answer (score 4):

Go only this far:

```
foreach (var data in MyCollection.Where(x => x.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow")))
{
    data.DeliveryDate = MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate);
}
```

If the *compile-time* type of `x.DeliveryDate` is `string`, prefer:

```
foreach (var data in MyCollection.Where(x => x.DeliveryDate == "Tomorrow"))
{
    data.DeliveryDate = MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate);
}
```

Comment: This is a good way of doing it. Maintaining readability while offering a compact form. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
MyCollection = MyCollection.Select(data =>
{
    if (data.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow"))
        data.DeliveryDate = MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate);
    return data;
}).ToList();
```

Or, if you don't want any Semicolons in your code (I'll assume that you have a class named *Delivery* with a constructor just for the *DeliveryDate*):

```
MyCollection = MyCollection.Select(data => data.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow")
    ? new Delivery(MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate))
    : data).ToList();
```

However, I wouldn't suggest to use Linq in here. The only little bit useful use of Linq would be what Jeppe Stig Nielsen suggested.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
MyCollection.Where(d => d.DeliveryDate.Equals("Tomorrow"))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(d => d.DeliveryDate = MyMethodToConvert(DeliveryDate));
```